# What is the counterargument to "I was only following orders"?

Tags: ethics

This seems like a fairly compelling argument at least if you were in the military and especially in time of war. If you watch or read The Caine Mutiny, you know how incredibly seriously the USA military took (and perhaps still takes) what occurred in that story -- failure to follow orders or to actively challenge a superior officer could have resulted in the men being hanged in that story. And it was even more clear in the German military -- probably in many cases where people were tried as war criminals their failure to follow orders would have at a minimum resulted them being disciplined and probably they ran a high risk of being summarily executed and the orders they failed to carry out would have been carried out by someone else. How is a soldier to know when to not follow orders in a situation where the entire military structure strongly discourages this behavior in all cases?

Does the rank of the officer have an impact? Even a man like Eichmann was not the one who decided upon policy but was indeed implementing what had been ordered from above. And an individual soldier or guard has the weight of the entire structure on their shoulders -- it seems to me almost unthinkable for a private or the equivalent rank to take it upon themselves to decide not to carry out an order on a moral basis.

Comment: This is called [Nuremberg defense or *Befehlsnotstand*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superior_orders). It did not help Nazis in Nuremberg, but generally the results were mixed. Israel introduced a concept of 'blatantly unlawful orders' in 1957, and it was gradually adopted, at least officially, by other countries, including the US. The doctrine that the oath to defend the Constitution supersedes all orders was used to convict the perpetrators of the My Lai massacre in 1968, see [Ford, When Can a Soldier Disobey an Order?](https://warontherocks.com/2017/07/when-can-a-soldier-disobey-an-order/)

Comment: I guess context is a key factor. The OP takes examples from the US and German army in WW2, and while it was not uncommon for German soldiers to be summarily executed for mere incompetence, while Patton was dismissed for simply hitting privates. Those are two very different cultures, and obviously the Nazi one makes it easier for atrocious orders to be carried on.

Comment: Isn't the answer simple? Just do what you can justify to yourself as morally right or permissible. Sure, if a person follows orders despite knowing them to be immoral, the one who gave the orders shares some moral responsibility, but so does the one who follows...